# Cant use hombrew because of "bad cpu type one executable"

Tags: osx, homebrew

Here is my exact error message

```
Error: Bad CPU type in executable - otool
```

I can't run stuff like `brew install wine`

Any help please? I'm running OS X.

Comment: If you answer your own question, then put the answer in an answer section.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i just noticed this, since i am a very old mac user i found files in usr/bin that hasn't been touched since 2003. LOL. Thats when macs where PowerPC and thats what it is referring to as a bad cpu type.

I had some fun with my Xcode cd from 2003 and tried to see what happened when you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  2003 would still be a PowerPC based Macintosh.  Something Akin to the [PowerMac G4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Mac_G4).  Homebrew expects an Intel Based CPU  There are Linux Distros that support the altivac Processor Type.  See this [list](http://mac.linux.be/content/apple-powerpc-wiki).